# Session variable issue

Tags: php, session, caching, session-variables

I have a php5.6 application that runs fine until now. The query fetched based on logged in user_id session displays another logged in user data. 
Below is my code:
login.php

```
<?php require_once("functions.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT manguserid, mangpwd,passport, amount,home_addr, previous_schl, religion, gender, dob,state_origin, child_nationality,email, phone, alt_phone, surname, first_name, other_name, username, password, curr_year,curr_arm,year_of_grad,stud_status, a.stud_id as 'stud_id' FROM student_profile as a,  students_login as b WHERE `username` like '%$user_id%' AND username NOT LIKE '%BLOCKED%' AND `password`='$pwd' and a.stud_id=b.stud_id";

    //Establish data connection     
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $total = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($total>0){
    $_SESSION['stud_id'] = $row['stud_id'];

                echo "<script language='Javascript'>
                    window.location=\"home.php\"
                </script>";
} ?>
```

My home.php is a dashboard and the session_start() was initiated in it

Then I have a page report.php as shown below:

```
<?php require_once("functions.php");
$stud_id = $_SESSION['stud_id'];
$temp = explode(",", $_GET['u']);
$term = $temp[1];
$ss = $temp[0 ];

 if($ss == $_SESSION['ss']){
$table = 'student_profile';
 }

else{
$table = 'student_profile_'.str_replace('/','_',$ss);
}



mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);

$query_stud = "SELECT a.stud_id, surname, first_name, other_name, curr_year, curr_arm, stud_status, curr_session, passport FROM ".$table." as a WHERE a.stud_id='$stud_id'";

$stud = mysql_query($query_stud, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

$row_stud = mysql_fetch_assoc($stud);

$totalRows_stud = mysql_num_rows($stud);

$a = $row_stud['curr_year'];
$b = $row_stud['curr_arm'];

?>
```

My functions.php is as follows:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conn.php');

// start session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}

$logoutAction = "";

function logOut(){
    global $logoutAction;
    // ** Logout the current user. **
    $logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
    if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
      $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    }

    if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
      //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = NULL;
      $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
      $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
      $_SESSION['stud_id'] = NULL;
      unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
      unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
      unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);
      unset($_SESSION['stud_id']);

      $logoutGoTo = "login.php";
      if ($logoutGoTo) {
        header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
        exit;
      }
    }
}

function restrictUser(){
    //log out any user that attemps not to login
    //
    $MM_authorizedUsers = "";
    $MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;

    // *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
    function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
      // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
      $isValid = False; 

      // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
      // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
      if (!empty($UserName)) { 
        // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
        // Parse the strings into arrays. 
        $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
        $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
        if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
        // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
        if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
        if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
          $isValid = true; 
        } 
      } 
      return $isValid; 
    }

    $MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
    if (!((isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
      $MM_qsChar = "?";
      $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
      if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
      if (isset($QUERY_STRING) && strlen($QUERY_STRING) > 0) 
      $MM_referrer .= "?" . $QUERY_STRING;
      $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
      header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
      exit;
    }
}//restric user ends

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
```

Then lastly my conn.php as shown below:

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"

global $hostname_conn;
global $database_conn;
global $username_conn;
global $password_conn;
global $conn;

$hostname_conn = "localhost";
$database_conn = "dbname";
$username_conn = "dbusername";
$password_conn = "password";
$conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Like i said, the users see different reports in report.php belonging to another actively logged on user without using the same computer nor browser.

Comment: ok first, 5.4 on a live environment is not fair on your users. Sorry it had to be said :( anyway, without seeing code it's hard to help, and your description is not really too clear. What do you mean about logging in from another location and seeing someone's profile? Get rid of the entire last paragraph and explain more about the actual issue :)

Comment: You had better show us some Example code that demonstrates this rather unbelievable situation. It has to be your code as this is a long way from normal

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question.

Comment: If data is being presented to the wrong user, then you are not identifying the users correctly. You need a unique ID for each user, usually "username" or "userID" etc. Then when they login you set a session (or whatever) that is just set on that users device. When they request data it should go in the DB and select that data based on their unique user ID. Without seeing your code it's impossible to say why this is happening.

Comment: Your edit is not worth anything . You should read the how to ask.

Comment: Thanks James, I edited the question again. please check if my question is clearer now. Forgive me am not a frequent stackoverflow user

Comment: If you have a problem with your teeth you bring them to the dentist to have a look. If you have a problem with your car you bring the car to the repair shop and let them have a look. Right? This seems to go smoothly. Now, let's say you have a problem with your code and you want the programmers to have a look, *what do you bring?*

Comment: Your question only includes **what you think the code does**. Not what it is. Since you are so reluctant to show us the code I believe a rubber duck is what you need. It will help you debug the code. Much better than we can in the stat the question is currently. https://rubberduckdebugging.com

Comment: I get your point Andreas, i just don't know where to start. very long procedural php code. OMG! Can i just paste some part?

Comment: Hello James and @Andreas, thanks for your assistance so far. I have included the code. Hope my question is clearer now. thanks for your anticipated responses.

Comment: @Andreas please help, my question is on hold. I need urgent assistance for God's sake. thanks

Comment: Oh my dear sweet wow.  Your first query is shockingly bad.  You are storing unencrypted passwords in your database.  AND you are targeting usernames with `LIKE`. AND you are not using prepared statements with placeholders. It's almost like you are trying to generate code with the least possible security/reliability/accuracy.  Also, you don't need a conditional session_start, just call the function unconditionally.  Stop using `mysql_`; use `mysqli_` functions.  If this were my code, I would be inclined to do a complete rewrite.

Comment: Honestly am also ashamed of the code. I wrote it since 2010 but the client didn't pay for me to upgrade until recent time. I am actually rewriting the app entirely with Laravel but i need this running without spending too much effort on the old script in ordr to focus attention on the new app. It worked fine before now, am just curious why not again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a directory to store session on my root directory.
Then i included the following in my code:

```
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","3600"); // 1 hours
ini_set("session.save_path", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mysession");
session_start();
```

That solved my problem and my session works as normal as before. Apparent the path was missing for a reason known to God.